# Highlight a checkbox when an other check box is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple checkboxes that have the same ID for different screen resolutions. When I click on the Check 1 label the checkmark gets highlighted. In the example provided both check 1 and check2 have the same IDs, when I click on check 1 I want the check mark of check 2 too also be highlighted and vice versa.

```css
.checkmark {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  /*height: 22px;*/
  height: 17px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.checkmark::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 11px;
  top: 6px;
}

.checkmark {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 8px;
  top: 12px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:after {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(42, 104, 149) 0px, rgb(44, 109, 157) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-lg">
  <label style="display: inline;color: #545454;font-weight:100;" dataid="' +this.ID +'">
    <input type= "checkbox" style= "display:none;" id="10A">Check1
    <span for="10A" class="checkmark"></span >
  </label >
</div>
                            
<div class="menu-sm">
  <label style="display: inline;color: #545454;font-weight:100;"  dataid="' +this.ID +'" >
    <input type= "checkbox" style= "display:none;" id="10A">Check2
    <span for="10A" class="checkmark"></span >
  </label >
</div>
```

How do I highlight all the checkmarks of the same IDS?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: Why don't you put a name for each of the checkboxes and write a function to update their state using JS, when any checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Comment: @j08691 sorry i forgot to mention the ID is unique,its just when the page resizes the div wrapping changes from menu-lg to menu-sm.so i added two checkboxes to show what its doing.when you higlight it on menu-lg it doesnt get highlighted on menu-sm

Comment: It's doable with CSS only but not with that HTML structure. The "+" operator only works on siblings so you'd have to jump through a lot of hoops (come up with HTML and CSS that keeps everything the same visually) to get that working. That's why JS was invented.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting is in your case based on the `:checked` selector -> if the checkbox is checked, the `span` behind it is highlighted.

In your case you will need javascript to react on the `onchange` / `click` event on the checkbox and trigger the other checkbox aswell.

A basic setup how to use it, you will need to alter that to your needs:

```
// use click or onchange
document.getElementById('checkbox1').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('checkbox2').click();
});
```

Comment: What if I check the checkbox using keyboard?

Comment: Thats why I told him to use the change handler if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this javascript code.

This code does the following:

- Add an event listener to the `change` event of both check boxes.
- Set the checked property of the other checkbox to the same value as the checked property of the checkbox where the change event triggered on.

**Note: I changed the id's of the check boxes to make them unique.**

```js
document.getElementById('10A-1').addEventListener('change', function () {
    document.getElementById('10A-2').checked = this.checked;
});

document.getElementById('10A-2').addEventListener('change', function () {
    document.getElementById('10A-1').checked = this.checked;
});
```

```css
.checkmark {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  /*height: 22px;*/
  height: 17px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.checkmark::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 11px;
  top: 6px;
}

.checkmark {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 8px;
  top: 12px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:after {
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(42, 104, 149) 0px, rgb(44, 109, 157) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-lg">
  <label style="display: inline;color: #545454;font-weight:100;" dataid="' +this.ID +'">
    <input type= "checkbox" style= "display:none;" id="10A-1">Check1
    <span for="10A-1" class="checkmark"></span >
  </label >
</div>
                            
<div class="menu-sm">
  <label style="display: inline;color: #545454;font-weight:100;"  dataid="' +this.ID +'" >
    <input type= "checkbox" style= "display:none;" id="10A-2">Check2
    <span for="10A-2" class="checkmark"></span >
  </label >
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

//Run it after document ready

```
var checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $(checkbox).on('click', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(checkbox).prop('checked', true);
    }
      else{
        $(checkbox).prop('checked', false);

      }
    });
```